# Can't read a file with null bytes?

Tags: c#, file-io, null

Hey guys I'm trying to read this file that has null bytes ( 00 hex ) sort of like padding. Every time I try to read the text it stops at the first null byte ( 00 hex ) does anybody know how to get around this?

Comment: Do you try to load this file as a text-file? If your file contains 0x0s, you have to read it in binary mode.

Comment: Can you post your code to read the file? It sounds like it is being interpreted as a string ( where 0x00 signifies the end of the string ).

Comment: @IanNorton  Yes this is what I have been doing. If i read it in binary how can i convert it to a string with out it ending like that?

Comment: the 0 byte is internal the end of a string. You will have to find a different method of reading. You can read text file if you know the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to read it as binary data and then few instructions at this link to handle your byte data. [Removing trailing nulls from byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240258/removing-trailing-nulls-from-byte-array-in-c)

Comment: Thanks, I just tested it and it seemed to work after removing all the nulls.

Answer (score 1):

Use [File.ReadAllBytes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx).

Comment: Now if i do this how could I use something like split on it seeing as it is not a string?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, using FileReadAllBytes, of reading an otherwise "text" file that contains hex 00 nulls as well as other special characters.

Background: The old Borland Database Engine from Paradox and Delphi days has a config file, named either IDAPI.CFG or IDAPI32.CFG.  The file is mostly normal text, but also contains the ASCII characters 0 (null) through 4.  I needed to read this file to determine the current value of the "NET DIR" setting, and skip over the nulls.

The approach:
1) Read the file as a stream of bytes, in one big (or small) gulp into a byte array. The important statement is 
`byte[filecontents] = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName).`

2) Read and process each character in the byte array.  For each character...
* If null, ignore it
* If other selected character, (ASCII 01 thru 04) either ignore it or transform to a different character representing its function, e.g., NewLine or equals sign. 
* If other (e.g. displayable) ASCII character, transform the byte back into a character form and append to an output stringbuilder.  The line of code that does this is  `textOut.Append((char)fileByte)`

```
        private string GetBDEConfigText(string fileName)
    {
        StringBuilder textOut = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        foreach (byte fileByte in fileContents)
        {
            switch (fileByte)
            {
                case 0:
                    {
                        // Leave unchanged, strip out binary character
                        break;
                    }
                case 1:
                    {
                        // Leave unchanged, strip out binary character
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        textOut.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                        break;
                    }
                case 4:
                    {
                        textOut.Append('=');
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        textOut.Append((char)fileByte);
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
        return textOut.ToString();
    }
```